# How to print multiple lists for item name and qty formatted?

Tags: python

I have an inventory program, options 1-4 work. The current problem is option 5. It currently prints all items and qty in brackets.

Like:

Item:      ['Chicken', 'Oranges', 'Turkey']

Quantity:  [12, 44, 22]

---

I need it to print like:

Item : Chicken

Quantity : 12

---

Item : Oranges

Quantity : 44

---

Item : Turkey

Quantity : 22

---

To duplicate my error type 1, type in Chicken, qty 12(adding item/qty to inventory), type 98, (repeat for more items) then type 5(Current inventory).

How do I fix this?

Full Code:

```
import os


name = []

qty = []

class Foo():
    def __init__(self, name, qty):
        self.name = name
        self.qty = qty

def menuDisplay():
    print ('=============================')
    print ('= Inventory Management Menu =')
    print ('=============================')
    print ('(1) Add New Item to Inventory')
    print ('(2) Remove Item from Inventory')
    print ('(3) Update Inventory')
    print ('(4) Search Item in Inventory')
    print ('(5) Print Inventory Report')
    print ('(99) Quit')
    CHOICE = int(input("Enter choice: "))
    menuSelection(CHOICE)

def menuSelection(CHOICE):

    if CHOICE == 1:
        print('Adding Inventory')
        print('================')
        new_name = input('Enter the name of the item: ')
        name.append(new_name)
        new_qty = int(input("Enter the quantity of the item: "))
        qty.append(new_qty)
        CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
    if CHOICE == 98:
        menuDisplay()
    elif CHOICE == 99:
        exit()
    elif CHOICE == 2:
        print('Removing Inventory')
        print('==================')
        removing = input('Enter the item name to remove from inventory: ')
        indexdel = name.index(removing)
        name.pop(indexdel)
        qty.pop(indexdel)
        CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
    if CHOICE == 98:
        menuDisplay()
    elif CHOICE == 99:
        exit()
    elif CHOICE == 3:
        print('Updating Inventory')
        print('==================')
        item = input('Enter the item to update: ')
        update = int(input("Enter the updated quantity. Enter 5 for additional or -5 for less: "))
        if update >= 0:
            qty[name.index(item)] += update
            print("Update made")
            CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
            if CHOICE == 98:
                menuDisplay()
            elif CHOICE == 99:
                exit()
        elif update <= -1:
            qty[name.index(item)] += update
            print("Update Made")
            CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
            if CHOICE == 98:
                menuDisplay()
            elif CHOICE == 99:
                exit()
    elif CHOICE == 4:
        print('Searching Inventory')
        print('===================')
        search = input('Enter the name of the item: ')
        pos = name.index(search) if search in name else -1
        if (pos >= 0):
            print ('Item:     ', name[pos])
            print ('Quantity: ', qty[pos])
            print ('----------')
        else:
            print("Item not in inventory")
        CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
        if CHOICE == 98:
            menuDisplay()
        elif CHOICE == 99:
            exit()
    elif CHOICE == 5:
        print('Current Inventory')
        print('=================')
        print ('Item:     ', name)
        print ('Quantity: ', qty)
        print ('----------')
        CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
    if CHOICE == 98:
        menuDisplay()
    elif CHOICE == 99:
        exit()

menuDisplay()
```

Comment: It seems your program prints a whole list but you want it to print a single item from the list only. Did you already read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists?

Comment: I want for it to print all items at once. By name /n qty /n ----------- then repeat for the next item.

Comment: And have you already read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements, where you learn how you can repeat some code for every item in a list?

Comment: thank you for the link I will look through it

Comment: And you should also read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques, where you learn how you can use `zip` to loop over two lists in parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Item = ['Chicken', 'Oranges', 'Turkey']

Quantity = [12, 44, 22]

zipo = list(zip(Item, Quantity))

print("\n\n\n")
for foobar in zipo:
    print("Item : ",foobar[0], "\nQuantity : ",foobar[1])
    print("______________________________________________")
```